# How to change the Update Channel for Microsoft Office 365 Apps?

Tags: batch-file, office365

I want my users to be on the Semi-Annual channel that updates every 6 months for stability. For my own system I want to be on the current version of Office so I can get all the new features and work through any bugs before my users see them.

How do I change just my workstation to have a different update channel than how it was deployed by the ODT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished from an administrative command prompt.

Here is an example batch script:

```
REM Change O365 Update Channel
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe" /changesetting Channel=Current
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe" /update user
```

You can specify any valid channel setting here. They seem to change often but as of this writing the options are:

- Beta
- Current (Preview)
- Current
- Monthly Enterprise
- Semi-Annual Enterprise (Preview)
- Semi-Annual Enterprise